# Movie where man is fastened on table and ants are eating/torturing him

Tags: story-identification, movie, post-apocalyptic

As a kid, in the early 90s (maximum 91) or late 80s (87 till 89) I was in the cinema and saw some SciFi apocalyptic movie.

I only remember one scene when one man is fastened on some table and ants are eating/torturing him.

Does anybody have any idea the name of the movie?

Comment: What makes you describe the movie as apocalyptic? Can you add some detail by explaining that? Also, did the movie seem new or old at the time? Was the language English?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The post-apocalyptic setting and the scene with a man being eaten by ants (which weren't real - the torture device used in that scene created an illusion of the victim's worst fear) suggest that this could be [Solarbabies](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091981/), released in 1986.

The main plot concerned a group of teenagers rebelling against a government with the assistance of a glowing alien orb.

Comment: I check the trailer, look-like it is.

Comment: _Solarbabies_ has the [hand melting scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yIsqInq_YT0) but I can't find a reference to an ant eating scene. Looks like a few other people have also misremembered it though if the scene doesn't actually exist.